# Additional content element in TYPO3 menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, typo3, typoscript

I made a menu in TypoScript in which on drop down section I have list of subpages and list of news. The code of menu is working but it render the list of news after every subpage (subpage1 and list of news, subpage 2 and list of news... etc). I would like to have two 
independent element (one list of subpages and one list of news), but i don't know how to achieve that?

here is my menu code:

```
lib.header_main-menu = COA
lib.header_main-menu {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>
        entryLevel = 0

        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            noBlur = 1
            wrap = |
            expAll = 1

            NO = 1
            NO {
                ATagTitle.field = title
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            }
        }
        2 = TMENU
        2 {
            expAll = 1
            wrap = <div class="subnav-wrapper"><ul class="subnav">|</ul></div>

            NO = 1
            NO {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
                wrapItemAndSub.append = COA
                wrapItemAndSub.append {
                wrap = |
                10 = CONTENT
                10 < lib.header_menu_news
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can't you just make two menus, if they have to be separated?

Comment: They has to be in one div element

Comment: That's no reason, you can wrap them at will. I'll post it below, but maybe I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lib.header_main-menu = COA
lib.header_main-menu {
    wrap = <div>|</div>
    // this is section 10 of the COA
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>
        entryLevel = 0

        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            noBlur = 1
            wrap = |
            expAll = 1

            NO = 1
            NO {
                ATagTitle.field = title
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            }
        }
        2 = TMENU
        2 {
            expAll = 1
            wrap = <div class="subnav-wrapper"><ul class="subnav">|</ul></div>

            NO = 1
            NO {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            }
        }
    } 
    // this is section 20 of the COA
    // btw the next line isn't necessary, you do that (define the object type) in lib.header_menu_news already
    // 10 (would be 20 now) = CONTENT
    20 < lib.header_menu_news
    20.wrap = <h3>News</h3>|
}
```

actually, this comes to the same as putting them into the template separately

```
<div>###MENU###
<h3>News</h3>
###NEWSMENU###</div>
```

btw unless you use the lib.object in the Backend somewhere, I would use temp. instead - the latter are unset after building the page object, and my guess would be that this might be better for performance.

Comment: Thanks Urs for your help and tips (I will use temp object) :)